# iOS AES Data/String conversion

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsdata

I have used previously addressed hints on AES encryption on iphone.

```
    NSString *mystr= [[self encryptString:[message valueForKey:@"message"] withKey:@"password"] hexadecimalString];
    NSData *mydata= [self encryptString:[message valueForKey:@"message"] withKey:@"password"];
    NSLog (@"Immediate decrypt data: %@",[self decryptData:mydata withKey:@"password"]);
    NSLog (@"Immediate decrypt string: %@",[self decryptData:[mystr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] withKey:@"password"]);
```

The first NSLog correctly decodes the string, the second returns null.
Methods within this class:

```
+ (NSData*) encryptString:(NSString*)plaintext withKey:(NSString*)key {
return [[plaintext dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]   AES256EncryptWithKey:key];
}

+ (NSString*) decryptData:(NSData*)ciphertext withKey:(NSString*)key {
return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[ciphertext AES256DecryptWithKey:key]
                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;
}
```

and header for NSData (Encryption)

```
- (NSData *)AES256EncryptWithKey:(NSString *)key;
- (NSData *)AES256DecryptWithKey:(NSString *)key;
```

Comment: hexadecimal string simply returns value similar to -descrition, without spaces or brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first step

```
NSString *mystr= [[self encryptString:[message valueForKey:@"message"] withKey:@"password"] hexadecimalString];
```

you convert an `NSData` to `NSString` using the `hexadecimalString` method.
For example, if the encrypted data is `01 02 03` then `mystr` is `@"010203"`.

In your last step

```
NSLog (@"Immediate decrypt string: %@",[self decryptData:[mystr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] withKey:@"password"]);
```

you convert `NSString` back to `NSData` with `dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding`.
For example, `@"010203"` would be converted to the data `30 31 30 32 30 33`.

This are two different conversion processes, so you cannot expect to get the correct result.
You should probably do something like

```
NSLog (@"Immediate decrypt string: %@",[self decryptData:[mystr dataFromHexadecimal] withKey:@"password"]);
```

where `dataFromHexadecimal` is a method that converts a hexadecimal string back to `NSData` (the inverse method to `hexadecimalString`).

Comment: I did not realize that NSData was binary. Will use base64 I guess.